# Turn the pixels of Bitmap to greyscal

Tags: android, kotlin, pixel, android-bitmap

I need to to turn the actual values of the pixels of a Bitmap into greyscale.
I've found solutions where it adds a filter like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373860/convert-a-bitmap-to-grayscale-in-android)
The problem is: it just changes it on the screen for viewing while keeping it as is. I need to change the actual bitmap to work on the pixels later and saving.
I tried to read about the color theory but got lost more

Comment: It's actually creating a new bitmap with grayscale, you have to save that in a new file to get an actual image file.

Comment: Pretty similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67656634/10534012